# DefaultPartitioner vs TimeBasedPartitioner S3 upload performance difference with 100 partitions and 50K flush size

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

I'm using a **100 Partition** topic with 3 Replicas and 2 ISR in a MSK serverless cluster.

My EC2 instance running the Confluent S3 sink connector ingests **56 GB** data from my MSK cluster in **15 minutes** and uploads only **37GB** data to S3 in the same time frame. The instance's resources are underutilized and I'm using a S3 endpoint which makes me think that this upload differential occurs due to my flush size and Partitioning  scheme.

My S3 sink connector config.

```
tasks.max=50
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
flush.size=50000
rotate.interval.ms=-1
rotate.schedule.interval.ms=-1
```

Based on my understanding, the current config waits for 50,000 messages to accumulate for each partition before uploading the file to S3.So, if I use a Time based Hourly Partitioner, this 50k message limit would be reached much more quickly as there is only 1 partition for the 15 minute time frame instead of a 100?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this mean? "there is only 1 partition for the 15 minute time frame instead of a 100"

Answer (score 0):

Each task has its own flush buffer. Hourly partitioner will buffer either the whole hour or dump each set of 50000 records within the hour partition, whichever occurs first.